# AS 3.0. fileReference download - не работает на веб-странице

Tags: flash, adobe, actionscript, swf

Суть такова.

Написал простенькое приложение, которое должно загружать файл из интернета и сохранять на компьютере. Когда компилирую в `Adobe Flash`, все работает: открывается диалоговое окно, я выбираю место сохранения файла, и он успешно скачивается.

Когда делаю `Publish`, вставляю `swf` на веб-страницу и пробую скачать файл, появляется диалоговое окно, я нажимаю "Сохранить" и далее ничего не происходит. При этом никаких ошибок не происходит и никакие обработчики событий не вызываются.

Прошу помочь советом, что делать и куда копать в данной ситуации.